# Android local database SQLite DLL Import

Tags: android, sqlite, mono, xamarin

My local DB works but It's a little slow.
I am using `Mono.Data.Sqlite` library.

From what I could find online, I believe these messages are because I am running different threads. And each time the DB files are requires, it tries to find them.  Is there any way to avoid searching for it every time? I am new to Android so please give me some details, if possible.

```
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/libsqlite.so' ('/system/lib/libsqlite.so').
[Mono] Searching for 'sqlite3_column_decltype'.
[Mono] Probing 'sqlite3_column_decltype'.
[Mono] Found as 'sqlite3_column_decltype'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/libsqlite.so' ('/system/lib/libsqlite.so').
[Mono] Searching for 'sqlite3_column_type'.
[Mono] Probing 'sqlite3_column_type'.
[Mono] Found as 'sqlite3_column_type'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/libsqlite.so' ('/system/lib/libsqlite.so').
[Mono] Searching for 'sqlite3_column_int64'.
[Mono] Probing 'sqlite3_column_int64'.
[Mono] Found as 'sqlite3_column_int64'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/libsqlite.so' ('/system/lib/libsqlite.so').
[Mono] Searching for 'sqlite3_column_text'.
[Mono] Probing 'sqlite3_column_text'.
[Mono] Found as 'sqlite3_column_text'.
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #8
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/libsqlite.so' ('/system/lib/libsqlite.so').
[Mono] Searching for 'sqlite3_bind_int'.
[Mono] Probing 'sqlite3_bind_int'.
[Mono] Found as 'sqlite3_bind_int'.
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #9
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/libsqlite.so' ('/system/lib/libsqlite.so').
[Mono] Searching for 'sqlite3_bind_null'.
[Mono] Probing 'sqlite3_bind_null'.
[Mono] Found as 'sqlite3_bind_null'.
Thread started:  #10
Thread finished:  #10
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/libsqlite.so' ('/system/lib/libsqlite.so').
[Mono] Searching for 'sqlite3_bind_double'.
[Mono] Probing 'sqlite3_bind_double'.
[Mono] Found as 'sqlite3_bind_double'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/libsqlite.so' ('/system/lib/libsqlite.so').
[Mono] Searching for 'sqlite3_column_name'.
[Mono] Probing 'sqlite3_column_name'.
[Mono] Found as 'sqlite3_column_name'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/libsqlite.so' ('/system/lib/libsqlite.so').
[Mono] Searching for 'sqlite3_column_double'.
[Mono] Probing 'sqlite3_column_double'.
[Mono] Found as 'sqlite3_column_double'.
```

That is my console log and I keep getting that.  I can see that it takes time to search and it's messing with performance. What can I do?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: ever figure this issue out? having something similar

Comment: @InitLipton sorry no I couldn't figure out how to get rid of that. For my solution, i just re-wrote some stuff and just optimized and it helped.  Sorry